# TFS serverside project alerts

Tags: tfs

It is our policy that the owner of a bug MUST be notified about bugs he owns, regardlessly of if he subscibed or forgot to subscribe. Is there a way project alerts can be configured on the server side or something without having to rely on the team member to subscribe manually? (TFS2010, TFS2008).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For TFS 2010 there is an easy solution for you now, via a plugin which can be downloaded from
[CodePlex - Team Alert](http://teamalert.codeplex.com/releases/view/62897)

It's a simple copy-paste solution which can take you 5 minutes to put in place using the configuration extract listed in the post below:

This post will show the exact configuration you need to perform what you want.
[Notify AssignedTo user of new work (for a specific TFS project)](http://teamalert.codeplex.com/discussions/355057#post893398)

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box!

If you are using TFS2008 then you can use http://tfseventhandler.codeplex.com to host an "Event Handler" to do this for you.

You may need to create your own handler if there is not one that suits your needs perfectly, but I think the "AssignedTo" handler will do the job.